# Why to use "do" with galaxies instead of "does"?

Tags: word-usage

Example: Do galaxies form around supermassive black holes, or do supermassive black holes form in the center of galaxies?

A galaxy isn't a third person? Like he, she, it?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the notion of grammatical "person".  Substitute "entity".  "it" is not a person in your sense either. **Galaxies** is a plural noun, hence **do**. It does. They do. There it is a question of grammatical *number*.

Comment: _A_ galaxy is an it, yes; two galaxies are not an it, but a they. This is something which is true in the vast majority of languages, including Portuguese (which I’m guessing is your own language, based on your name): would you consider _As galáxias forma-se…_ to be correct? Presumably not, because _As galáxias **formam**-se…_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: "Vast majority of languages"?  What do you know of languages not of Indo-European type?

Comment: @GEdgar That was rather broadly put, yes; I should have specified the majority of languages that represent grammatical number in both (pro)nouns and verbs. Naturally, it’s not generally the case in Sino-Tibetan or Austronesian languages, Japanese, etc., but apart from Indo-European languages, it is the case in Eskimo-Aleutic languages, Bantu languages, Uto-Aztecan languages, etc. And no, of course I’m not familiar with all 6,000+ languages in the world; it was hyperbole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb *doing* conjugates to „do“ in 3rd person plural form. (Lookup the conjugation tables for *doing* for proof)

**3rd person plural**:
Do galaxies form around supermassive black holes?
Do supermassive black holes form in the center of galaxies?

**3rd person singular**:
Does a galaxy form around a supermassive black hole?
Does a supermassive black hole form in the center of a galaxy?